# Correctly disposing Persistent<ArrayBuffer>

Tags: c++, v8, arraybuffer

I got very simple code:

```
struct Dyn {
 float *ptr;
 int n;
};


void setWeakFunction1(const WeakCallbackInfo<Dyn> &data) {
}
void setWeakFunction(const WeakCallbackInfo<Dyn> &data) {
 auto *v = data.GetParameter();
 data.SetSecondPassCallback(setWeakFunction1);
 std::cout << v->n << " Collector\n";
 delete[] v->ptr;
 delete v;

}

void getIndex(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args) {
  Dyn *d = new Dyn;
  float *ptr = new float[amount];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < amount; ++i) {
    ptr[i] = i + 2;
  }

  auto isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  HandleScope scope(isolate);
  Local<ArrayBuffer> ab =
      ArrayBuffer::New(isolate, ptr, amount * sizeof(float));
  Persistent<ArrayBuffer> pab(isolate, ab);
  pab.SetWeak(d, setWeakFunction, WeakCallbackType::kInternalFields);
  pab.MarkIndependent();
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(ab);
}

void RegisterModule(Local<Object> exports, Local<Object>) {
 auto isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
 exports->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "getIndex"),
           FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, getIndex)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(commander, RegisterModule)
```

This code work somehow awkward for me.

Since there're a counter, I expect, that `setWeakFunction` is called for every `Persistence` storage I have created. When amounts of floats less than 10000, it called for every single Persistent cell. But when size of floats become `100 000`, it does not tryes to dispose any of the objects until there's 1Gb of memory eaten, then it remove constantly, but leaving 2-3 objects.

I had a thought, that garbage collector calls `WeakCallback` once for a bunch of objects, but didn't find information, confirming this.

Even worse, I had never seen any garbage collecting calls for `1000 000` float arrays.

How to dispose this arrays correctly?

Comment: it looks like awkward code. There is no garbage collection in c++, nor is it needed.

Comment: @RichardHodges, Did you mention `v8`, and `arraybuffer` tags?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to fix the above code:

```
struct Dyn {
    Persistent<ArrayBuffer> pab;
    float *ptr;
    int n;
};

void setWeakFunction(const WeakCallbackInfo<Dyn> &data) {
    auto *v = data.GetParameter();
    std::cout << v->n << " Collector\n";
    v->pab.Reset();
    delete[] v->ptr;
    delete v;

}

void getIndex(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args) {
    Dyn *d = new Dyn;
    float *ptr = new float[amount];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < amount; ++i) {
        ptr[i] = i + 2;
    }

    auto isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);
    Local<ArrayBuffer> ab =
        ArrayBuffer::New(isolate, ptr, amount * sizeof(float), ArrayBufferCreationMode::kExternalized);
    d->pab.Reset(isolate, ab);
    d->pab.SetWeak(d, setWeakFunction, WeakCallbackType::kParameter);
    d->pab.MarkIndependent();
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(ab);
}

void RegisterModule(Local<Object> exports, Local<Object>) {
    auto isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    exports->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "getIndex"),
        FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, getIndex)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(commander, RegisterModule)
```